# How to launch golang application from VS Code when in internal module

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, debugging, module

When I am editing a .go source file like that PROJECT_DIR/internal/moduleABC/moduleABC.go and press Start Debugging I get this message "Failed to launch: could not launch process: not an executable file" and then I need to navigate to any of the files in PROJECT_DIR and start debugging again.

Very annoying, maybe someone know a way to fix this.

Thx

Hopefully there is a solution not just for one single module but for all of them.

Comment: Just configure your `launch.json` as suits your workflow: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/debugging#configure

Answer (score 1):

I edited   launch.json and replaced

```
"program": "${fileDirname}"
```

with

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}"
```

and now the main app is launched even if I am in an internal module folder

full launch.json file

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That solved my problem. Thanks a lot! A little bit of context here: In GO, running a file is different than running a module. You can also see it when you run through cli: `go run main.go` and `go run .` will rely on the very same concepts.

Comment: Note: I got the same error due to a bad environment variable. In the explorer, open the Go/env section. For me, I had GOOS set to an incorrect value.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're encountering an issue with launching a Golang application from VS Code, especially when working with internal modules. To address this problem, you can follow these steps:

1. **Specify the Entry Point:**
   Ensure that you have specified the correct entry point for your Go application in the launch configuration. Open your **.vscode/launch.json** file, and make sure that the "**program**" field points to the correct main file or package. For example:

> ```
> {   "version": "0.2.0",   
>      "configurations": [
> {
>   "name": "Launch",
>   "type": "go",
>   "request": "launch",
>   "mode": "debug",
>   "program": "${workspaceFolder}/internal/moduleABC",
>   "env": {},
>   "args": []
> }   ] }
> ```

2. **Use Delve Debugger:** Ensure that you have the Delve debugger installed. Delve is a debugger for the Go programming language. You can install it using:

> ```
> go get -u github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
> ```

Then, set the "**useApiV1**" field to '**false**' in your
**launch.json**:

```
{   "version": "0.2.0",   "configurations": [
{
  "name": "Launch",
  "type": "go",
  "request": "launch",
  "mode": "debug",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/internal/moduleABC",
  "env": {},
  "args": [],
  "useApiV1": false
}   ] }
```

3. **Check Go Module Configuration:**
   Make sure your project is using Go modules. If not, initialize modules in your project:

> ```
> go mod init
> ```

Ensure that your **go.mod** file has the correct module path.

4. **Update VS Code and Go Extension:**
   Ensure that both VS Code and the Go extension are up to date. Extension updates often include bug fixes and improvements.
5. **Reload Window:**
   After making changes to your configuration, try reloading the VS Code window. You can do this by clicking on the circular arrow icon in the bottom-left corner of the window.

If the issue persists, please provide more details about your project structure and the content of your **launch.json** file, so I can offer more targeted assistance.

Comment: This actually makes the debugging start for the module and not the main application but thx for the idea